# How to schedule a .NET Core micro service?

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi, apigee

**Question 1**

I have an ASP.NET Core micro service fetching the order status from the order table in SQL Server 2016. I want this micro service to be run every 5 minutes to check for new orders. We have an apigee API gateway but I don't think we can schedule any micro service in the apigee gateway(I am new to API gateway).

How can I schedule a micro service to run every x minutes?

**Question 2**

Can we host a .NET micro service in Autosys?

Comment: try quartz https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Cron Jobs: https://blog.devart.com/scheduling-cron-jobs-in-asp-net-6-and-c.html

Or you could use schedule an Azure function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function